# ROUNDUP Formulas in VBA over a dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where the range is dynamic. I want to find the max value of this dynamic range. Here is the chunk of my code where I am trying to find the max value

```
Set SearchRng1 = Cells(2, 2)
    Debug.Print SearchRng1.Address
    Set SearchRng2 = Cells(LastRow, j + 2)
    Debug.Print SearchRng2.Address

    With hidden3ws
    Worksheets("Hidden3").Activate
    Range("B2").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(MAX('Incre_Calc_A'!SearchRng1:SearchRng2),-1)"
    End With
```

But the output of this is = #NAME? 
Can someone help me with this code so I can get an actual value? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do not use `Worksheets("Hidden3").Activate` when refering to cells on worksheet "Hidden3" .... use `Worksheets("Hidden3").Range("B2").Formula = ....` to refer to cell directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the variables from the string and concatenate:

```
Set SearchRng1 = Cells(2, 2)
Debug.Print SearchRng1.Address
Set SearchRng2 = Cells(LastRow, j + 2)
Debug.Print SearchRng2.Address

With hidden3ws
Worksheets("Hidden3").Activate
Range("B2").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(MAX('Incre_Calc_A'!" & SearchRng1.Address & ":" & SearchRng2.Address & "),-1)"
End With
```